# Mapping Array (text, data) in Elasticsearch Kibana

Tags: arrays, json, elasticsearch, tags, kibana

I´m trying to post these Tags:

```
POST dicom1/_doc/1
        {
          "(0008,0005)": ["SpecificCharacterSet", "ISO_IR 100"], 
          "(0008,0008)": ["ImageType", "ORIGINAL"], 
          "(0008,0020)": ["StudyDate", "2002-04-01"],
          "(0008,0023)": ["ContentDate", "2002-04-01"],
    ... 
    }
```

But I get this exception:

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "mapper [(0008,0020)] of different type, current_type [date], merged_type [text]"
```

So i tried:

```
PUT dicom1
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc":{
    "properties": {
      "(0008,0020)": {
        "type": ["text","date"],
      },
      "(0008,0023)": {
        "type": ["text" ,"date"],
      },
...
```

But it says "Bad String"
How can I post my json, without changing the structure?

Comment: A field cannot have multiple data types. You would need to create separate fields to handle each type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DICOM has a set of standards as how the image naming conventions should go about.

What you have as an array is a key-value in itself. Basically, you have something called as `tag`, `tag name` and the `value` for that particular image.

In short, you can say that you have tuples. For e.g.

```
tag - "(0008,0020)"
tag_name - "StudyDate"
tag_value - 2004-01-01
```

I've come up with the below design for DICOM images and I like to think it would work for most of the use-cases. Please see below mapping, sample documents, the query and the response as how it appears:

### Mapping:

```
PUT dicom
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "dicom_tags_text":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "tag": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "tag_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "tag_value":{
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "dicom_tags_date":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "tag": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "tag_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "tag_value":{
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
          }
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Below are some of the concepts I've used

- [Nested Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)
- [Text Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/text.html)       -----> Used for partial matches
- [Keyword Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)    -----> Used for exact matches
- [Date Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html).

Every image would have two categories of data, the ones with `text` field and the ones with `date` field. You can add more fields depending on if you want to store any other format of data.

Note that for the sake of simplicity I've made use of keyword for string data. That is because they are used for exact match. You can use `text` data too but please spend sometime in understanding the difference between two.

### Sample Documents:

```
POST dicom/_doc/1
{
  "dicom_tags_text": [
    {
      "tag": "(0008,0005)",
      "tag_name": "SpecificCharacterSet",
      "tag_value": "ISO_IR 100"
    },
    {
      "tag": "(0004,1511)",
      "tag_name": "SOPInstanceId",
      "tag_value": "1001"
    }
  ],
  "dicom_tags_date": [
    {
      "tag": "(0008,0020)",
      "tag_name": "StudyDate",
      "tag_value": "2002-04-01"
    },
    {
      "tag": "(0008,0023)",
      "tag_name": "ContentDate",
      "tag_value": "2002-04-01"
    }  
  ]
}

POST dicom/_doc/2
{
  "dicom_tags_text": [
    {
      "tag": "(0008,0005)",
      "tag_name": "SpecificCharacterSet",
      "tag_value": "ISO_IR 100"
    },
    {
      "tag": "(0004,1511)",
      "tag_name": "SOPInstanceId",
      "tag_value": "1004"
    }
  ],
  "dicom_tags_date": [
    {
      "tag": "(0008,0020)",
      "tag_name": "StudyDate",
      "tag_value": "2020-01-01"
    }  
  ]
}
```

Note that I've created two documents above and notice carefully how I've constructed the documents. You can cross-check this with the mapping to understand the mapping in first place.

### Request Query:

Now let's say your use case is to retrieve all documents with `ISO_IR 100` charset having `StudyDate` done after `2019-01-01`.

Below is how the query would be:

```
POST dicom/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "dicom_tags_text",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "dicom_tags_text.tag_name": "SpecificCharacterSet"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "dicom_tags_text.tag_value": "iso ir 100"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "dicom_tags_date",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "dicom_tags_date.tag_name": "StudyDate"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "dicom_tags_date.tag_value": {
                        "gte": "2019-01-01"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that for [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) datatype we need to make use of [`nested queries`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html). I've made use of [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) for [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) types and used simple [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) for [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/text.html) field. Please read the aforementioned links to understand more on this.

### Below is how response appears:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.4854383,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "dicom",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 2.4854383,
        "_source" : {
          "dicom_tags_text" : [
            {
              "tag" : "(0008,0005)",
              "tag_name" : "SpecificCharacterSet",
              "tag_value" : "ISO_IR 100"
            },
            {
              "tag" : "(0004,1511)",
              "tag_name" : "SOPInstanceId",
              "tag_value" : "1004"
            }
          ],
          "dicom_tags_date" : [
            {
              "tag" : "(0008,0020)",
              "tag_name" : "StudyDate",
              "tag_value" : "2020-01-01"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Let me know if this is something that would help you!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. I could learn a lot from it! 
I have completely rebuilt it:                                                                                             `{
  "vol1":{
    "(0008,0008)": {"ImageType": "DERIVED"}, 
    "(0008,0016)": {"SOPClassUID": "1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4"}
  },
"vol2":{ },                                                                                                                "vol3":{ },            .. }`                           So mapping was no longer necessary.

Comment: Sure, just make sure you do understand your use-cases from querying perspective too. You have to have a good data model for your queries to be effective. Having a bad data model won't solve anything even if your querying logic is out of the world and vice versa. And don't forget to upvote the answer too ;)